# Doesn't grep function work with"("?

Tags: r, regex

This is my dataset

```
 userId               source           transactions
         (dbl)                      (chr)        (chr)              
1  1       google / cpc, google / cpc            0, 1            
2  2       (direct) / (none)                     0               
3  3       (direct) / (none)                     1               
4  4        google / organic, (direct) / (none)  0                 
5  5        google / organic                     0                  
6  6        google / organic                     0
```

I want to extract all of the rows contain `(direct) / (none)`

and I wrote the following code:

```
output<-df[grep("(direct) / (none)", df$source),]
```

But it results in an out put with 0 observations, it work well with others such as `google / cpc`. What is wrong? Is it the problem with "("?

This is dput

```
dput(df)
structure(list(userId = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10), source = c("google / cpc, google / cpc", 
"(direct) / (none)", "(direct) / (none)", "google / organic", 
"google / organic", "google / organic", "(direct) / (none)", 
"google / cpc, google / cpc, google / cpc, google / organic, google / cpc", 
"(direct) / (none)", "(direct) / (none)"), transactions = c("0, 1", 
"0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0, 0, 0, 0, 0", "0", "1")), .Names = c("userId", 
"source", "transactions"), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: You could skip using `grep` at all if just looking for a direct match `df[ df$source == "(direct) / (none)" , ]`

Comment: Sorry perhaps my example is not clease I want all the rows that contains "(direct) / (none)". For instance, if a source if a user is l, (direct) / (none) , a, b ,c , I need this one as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(` has [a special meaning in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). You should either escape it `\\(`

```
grep("\\(direct\\) / \\(none\\)", df$source)
```

or use `fixed = TRUE` which tells `grep` to interpret the pattern as-is.

```
grep("(direct) / (none)", df$source, fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you. the first option doesn't work perfectly, I got this error by using the second option: "unused argument (fixed = TRUE)"

Comment: Have you put `fixed = TRUE` in the right place? It is definitely an argument to `grep`.